# ES6 static method vs non-static and ES5 OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm a bit confused.

If, for example...:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
// so, the following will be shared, and this 
// is the best practice, right?:
Person.prototype.whatEver = function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
// the following will also be shared, but it's 
// bad practice, because it will be included in 
// each instances and take space(memory) for nothing. correct?
Person.whatEver = function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

if the above correct and I got this right, then why the hell would I ever need a static functions? because this:

```
Person.whatEver = function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

is exactly as this, correct?:

```
// it would need to be inside of the class, of course
static whatEver(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "included in each instance"? Have you tried calling the static `Person.whatEver` method on an instance?

Comment: @Bergi thanks, you pointed me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 4):

While this is equivalent to an ES6 static method, it's not doing what you think:

```
Person.whatEver = function(){
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

That puts the `whatEver` function on the `Person` *constructor*, not on an instantiated `person` - and the `Person` constructor probably does not have a `firstName` or `lastName`. You were probably thinking of

```
const person = new Person();
person.whatEver = function(){
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

in which case, yes, running code like that every time a Person is instantiated will result in lots of functions (one for each person) rather than just a single function on the prototype.

The use for static methods is generally *outside* of interactions with instantiated objects. Think of when you might want information associated with a class even if nothing has necessarily been instantiated yet. For example, you could have a static method on the Person class:

```
class Person {
  static canEat() {
    return ['apples', 'bananas', 'carrots'];
  }
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you pal, it helped

Answer (score 2):

```
//contstructor 
function Person () { … } 

//member method
Person.prototype.foo = function () { 
  console.log(this); 
}

//static method
Person.foo = function () { 
   console.log(this);
}
```

All function definitions are created only once in Memory. The diffrence is the »this context«:

```
new Person().foo(); // [Object Person] or Person {}

Person.foo(); // Person () {}
```

So that is why you cannot access member properties in a static function. `this` refers to the constructor function not to the instance. Under the hood, using the `new` operator will do something like this:

```
var obj = Person.call({}) // a new Object is created and passed as the
                          // »this context« and automatically returned.
```

If you would have:

```
function Person () {
  this.bar = function () { … }
}
```

a new function object would created in Memory for each instance (`new Person()`), but that is the particular property of the prototype chain. Calling a method on an instance, will cause the JS interpreter to first search all »own« properties and than go up the prototype chain to find the requested property. The `prototype` is shared by all instances, so its properties are only created once.

In ES6 it would look like this:

```
class Person(){

  static foo () {}

  constructor () {}

  bar () {}

}
```

Comment: But if so, then the `function Person () {
  this.bar = function () { … }
} ` should be considered a bad practice, correct(because of the memory)? But this will be equivalent to `Person.bar = function () { ... }` wouldn't it?

Comment: the first one creates new function objects, so better to avoid, especially if you a have a lot of instances — right. But the second will only be created once since it is a »own« Property of the `function Person(){}` object, not of the instances, created by `new Person()`

Comment: so basically it as if I'll say: `function Person() { function thePerson(){ ... } `, am I correct? if not, then what would be the analogy?

Comment: I am not sure what you are after. But `new Person()` will cause the constructor function (`function Person () {}`) to be executed. If you create a new function object with the function (`this.f = function () {}`) than this one will be stored in memory, since it is part of the instance created. In you comment above, the function would be created, but since it is not assigned to the instance, it will be target of the garbage collector and removed from memory, since it cannot be accessed in any way.

Comment: OMFG... I'm an idiot. the `Person.whatEver = function() {...}` will be applied only on the `Person`, so to say `Person.whatever(...)` and not its instances. the prototype version will share it among instances in a right way, without memory issues(compare to the inside function of the `Person` constructor) and will be accessible from instances as a result. So I got this thanks to you Philipp and others who helped me here, but one thing is eating me...: why is the `Person.whatEver` works? I mean the `Person` is a function, not an object... or is it because functions are also type of an object?hm

Answer (score 2):

> the following will also be shared, but it's bad practice,
>   because it will be included in each instances and take
>   space(memory) for nothing. correct?

This comes from the misunderstanding of how functions work in Javascript.

In `class`-based languages, when an instance of a class is created, all the method definitions, including the inherited ones, are **copied**.

Javascript is not `class`-based.

ES6 added `class` support, but it's only a sugar, and javascript `class` doesn't exactly act like classes in Java or C++ (or most other `class`ic languages)

`static` methods in Java or C++ doesn't require instantiation, which could be quite useful.

In Javascript, since there is no such thing as a class, or instantiation of a class, the methods do not get copied.
Only the reference to the function gets copied.

In your code

```
Person.whatEver = function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

For easier understanding, you can think of `Person` as an object with a function `whatEver`. So your 'static' method above is not too different from

```
let Person = {
  whatEver() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  },
  talk() {
    return 'I can talk';
  },
};
```

For example, you can call `Person.talk()` without instantiation.

However, for your `whatEver()` function, if you need to access `this` in it, it's not a good idea to declare it as a static function, because the assumption is that `this` points to the instantiated object.

Class models don't fit into javascript quite well, and the confusion often originates from that.

---

I want to add one more thing:

```
// so, the following will be shared, and this 
// is the best practice, right?:
Person.prototype.whatEver = function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

This is not true. All functions in Javascript is shared, and `Person.prototype.whatEver` and `Person.whatEver` are just two different ways of declaring functions.

`Person.prototype.whatEver` can be called on an object you create with `new Person(..)`, which is a constructor **call**. By this I mean when a function is called with `new`, an empty object gets created, `this` gets bound to this new object, and the object gets `prototype`-linked to `Person`.

So when you instantiate it like `var p = new Person(..)`, and call `p.whatEver()`, it will try to find `whatEver(..)` function **reference** in the prototype chain, and will find one in `Person.prototype`, which gets called.

Comment: Thank you Eric Na and ayushgp! :)

Answer (score 1):

> The following will also be shared, but it's bad practice, because it will be included in each instances and take space(memory) for nothing. correct?

No it won't. You see methods in JS are assigned as references to them. This method will be created once and not be repeated again and again for each object. They'll point to the same method. This is a static method only. So both definitions of the `whatEver` function are statically defining it on the Person class.

So if you have code like:

```
let firstPerson = new Person();
let secondPerson = new Person();
```

Both of these objects will have reference to the same instance method(the prototype one) `whatEver`. Now the `Person.whatEver` static method will also have a single copy which can be called directly on the `Person` class only and no instance of this class.

Comment: woops, I think I made a mistake... the `Person.prototype.whatEver = function(){` is actually a bad practice, because it will be shared... :/

Comment: Nooooooo. Again that never happens. Its all about references/pointers/whatever you want to call it. Copies of functions for the same class are not created. Type of function is irrelevant(instance and static methods both are created once only.)

Comment: @danedidug It *will* be shared among all instances, but that's a *good* thing, not a bad thing. Don't want to create 1000 functions when you can simply use one on the prototype instead

Comment: Thanks guys for the help :)